# Scons not found android_add_java_dir

Tags: android, scons

I'm using Scons to build godot engine and after i set everythings right:

I set my system variables as:

```
ANDROID_NDK_HOME --->  C:\android-ndk-r19c
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT --->  C:\android-ndk-r19c
ANDROID_HOME  --->  C:\Users\V\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

But Scons is like is not able to find android
what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the FAQ:

https://scons.org/faq.html#Why_doesn.27t_SCons_find_my_compiler.2BAC8-linker.2BAC8-etc..3F_I_can_execute_it_just_fine_from_the_command_line.

SCons doesn't propagate system shell environment variables by default, by design.